# Use DPAPI (Data Protector API) to unprotect data on different computer

Tags: c#, dpapi

I am using `DPAPI` (Data Protector API) to protect and unprotect data. I am reading data from the file.

> C:\Users\nandkishore.sharma\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\Default\WebData.

I am able to read the data from the file (`WebData`) if I decrypt data on the same computer(where `WebData` is placed). but When I pick the `WebData` file from another computer(where file is already encrypted), try to decrypt it at my computer, I am not able to do this.

I found this link 
[How to decrypt data which is crypted by CryptProtectData function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201146/how-to-decrypt-data-which-is-crypted-by-cryptprotectdata-function)

It says..

> "no other computer in the world can decrypt data which is encrypted on
>   different computer."

Is above statement true?

I read out below link but it did not solve my problem..
[Unable to Decrypt data on second computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23124000/unable-to-decrypt-data-on-second-computer)

How can I get the key which is used in encryption (in reference of `WebData` file) so that I can use the same key in decrypt?

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late but since theres no answer and I had the same question:
I believe it can be inferred from the documentation that this class is used for encrypting data by the currently executing program from other programs on the same machine [See reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.dpapidataprotector.scope?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks). So, even if it is possible to use it for encryption between different machines, this is not the original intent and it would be some kind of hack. It is better to find some other method of encryption that was designed to protect data between different machines - like SSL/TLS.